# Formula: convert text to date

Tags: formula

How would you convert `February 23, 2016` to a date value without using the `DATEVALUE` function? 
I get the #Error result from my formula if I use the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DATEVALUE` function is used to convert `Date/Time` values into just a `Date` value. If you want to convert a `Text` value into a `Date` value, try using `DATE(text)`. See [Using Date and Date/Time Values in Formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm) for more help with `Date` and `Date/Time` formulas.

Comment: Touched up  your formatting a bit. Hope you don't mind. Welcome to SFSE!

Comment: Haha no Adrian that is totally fine. Looks better now lol.

Comment: @loggedinuser please mark this as the best answer if it resolved your issue. If it did not then please let us know what is still not working.